# Multiplayer game with socket nodeJs, is DB needed?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I use socket on connection event. new players are created and seen, multiplayer array of objects in console, exists. However, not every event is seen properly (for example, 1. newest connections only see them self,  while older see everyone on game. 2. I want also to show all players movements , real time. Dont know how node can handle that). For those issues in brackets, do I need to use Mongo DB or index DB to handle all data real time ?

Comment: What data structures are you currently using to store players/connections? Are they in memory on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a database in order for your game to work in a distributed way i.e. so you can scale to more than more server / node process. If you are currently storing all connection/player data in memory, then this won't be accessible by other processes.

With regard to `newest connections only see them self, while older see everyone on game` I'd need to know more about how/where you store these connections.

For the second point, `I want also to show all players movements , real time`, I'll need more detail on how you are sending these movements from the client to server, & then broadcasting.